# How to use Laravel relationships to create a table?

Tags: database, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

[image]

as you see on the diagram :
the `task` belong to a `user` and a `project` on the same time.
the `user` and `project` can have multiple `tasks`.

how can i use `laravel relationships` to create a `task`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing comlicated. One task `belongsTo` project, and also one task `belongsTo user`.
User `hasMany` tasks, project `hasMany` tasks.

Task model:

```
public function user() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function project() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

Project model:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

Then when you are creating Tasks for project you can do:
`$project->tasks()->create([...]);`

Comment: and how can i use this relationship to create a `task` on the controller?

Comment: It depends on use case. For example as I wrote `$project->tasks()->create(['name' => 'Open door']);` will set project_id automatically based on $project ($project is Model of specific project).